# HTML/Download link

Tags: html, testing, firefox, netbeans, hyperlink

I need help with HTML version 5. The code is written in Apache NetBeans, but something is incorrect in the download section. The Browser (Firefox) does not open the window with the download option, just opens in the new tab.

Here is the code with `a` atribute.

```
<a href="documents/HTML-Links-Frontend.pdf" download="HTML">DOWNLOAD DOCUMENTS</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) is boolean, changing the html like this should work:

```html
<a href="documents/HTML-Links-Frontend.pdf" download>DOWNLOAD DOCUMENTS</a>
```

Comment: [1] Please only link to web sites in English. [2] In eight years on SO I have _never_ seen anyone link to a web site in German, yet two answers to this question both post identical links to a web site in German. That is an extraordinary coincidence!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) together with the about attribute = "_blank"

```
<a href="filename.pdf" download="name of the downloaded file" about="_blank">Download the pdf</a>
```

Be careful because download is not supported by IE [caniuse.com/#feat=download](https://caniuse.com/#feat=download)

Comment: [1] Please only link to web sites in English. [2] In eight years on SO I have _never_ seen anyone link to a web site in German, yet two answers to this question both post identical links to a web site in German. That is an extraordinary coincidence!